# How to add a string value to the results in a row

Tags: sql, string

I'm a beginner in SQL, and have an assingment I am working on that ask's for us to show the date and century. Although this is a really simple thing to do, I thought about adding in a string that separates the result of the century, like if the date is shown, and then I enter a string saying "current century -" with the century result following, and all of this being in the same row. Here's my code I am using to create the table and it's results:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month, DD, YYYY CC') AS "Today's Date and Century" FROM dual;
```

it produces this:

`Today's Date and Century`

`February , 05, 2014 21`

I can't seem to find anything that would let me add a string to the results right before, or even after the century part, so it can look like this:

`February , 05, 2014 Current Century - 21st`

Anybody got any ideas on how to go about doing this, or some links to where I can go to read about how to do this?

Comment: You can add any text in quotation marks within the format string

Comment: This script is not working in SQLR2!

Comment: I don't even know what SQLR2 is. I know this is done on a SQL 10g server, via web page access if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month, DD, YYYY "Current Century -" CC"st"') AS "Today's Date and Century" FROM dual;
```

you can insert *any text in quotations* within the format string

Comment: Yeah, I was posting that I sorted it out as you posted this, thanks anyway for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I went back and looked and noticed that the commas were off, and that I was missing one. Once I went in and changed them I realized I could just add in quotations and presto, everything worked. Now it just seems like a really stupid question after I see how simple it was.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month, DD, YYYY, "Current Century - " CC"st"') AS "Today's Date and Century" FROM dual;
```